# Compare Alamofire response with String

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to compare the answer that Alamofire returns with a series of values, But I do not understand how I should compare the response with a String. This is my code

```
Alamofire.request(urlRegister, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in

    let myResponse: String = response.result.value!
    if let data = response.data, let myResponse2 = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        if myResponse2 == "Insert" {
            print("Insert")
        } else if myResponse2  == "exists" {
            print("exists")
        } else {
            print("Conetion Error")
        }
    } 

}
```

I have also tried to store the response in a String variable, but it also does not allow me to make the comparison.I thank for any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you print `myResponse2` what gets printed?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine if the response has a valid `data`. But in `case` of `error`, you will not be able find a reason for unwanted result. Better to use the `response` `result` `enum` to get a clear idea of what is being happening as below,

```
    Alamofire.request(urlRegister, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            if value == "Insert" {
                print("This is insert!")
            } else if value == "exists" {
                print("Value exists!")
            } else {
                print("Some unwanted value!")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The answer comes from my PHP API hosted in a web service and send response echo "Insert" if the insertion occurred, However, I still have the same problem, I can not compare the String with the answer.

Comment: What is answer? In ‘success’ what is being printed on console?

Comment: Response1 :SUCCESS: Insertado9

Some unwanted value!

Comment: So in response the text (i.e, ‘Insertado9’) is different than expected text I.e, ‘Insert’ so it’s going into ‘else’ case. You need to correct your comparison statement.

Comment: in my code that difference is contemplated but in spite of it persists the error persists. Thank you very much for your help .switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                if value == "Insertado9" {
                    print("This is insert!")
                } else if value == "Existe6" {
                    print("Value exists!")
                } else {
                    print("Some unwanted value!")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error")
            }